# How to export finished design as one file in Adobe XD

Tags: adobe-xd

I tried to export my design as one (image) file from Adobe XD. I tried 'file > export' option, but this results in exporting every assets individually. What I want is to export my finished design as one file as it looks in Adobe XD. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option to do that, but there is a possible work around.

1. Draw a rectangle with no fill and stroke, same size and position as the artboard.
2. Select everything on the artboard (including the invisible rectangle), and group <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. With the group selected, do *Export > Selected*